# access cordova plugins from ionic controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I want to use [Cordova Email Plugin](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer) in ionic application.

I can access plugin in $ionicPlatform function but when I moved my code to my controller in a function for handle ng-click it is not work.

**Know my question is how to access cordova plugin objects from controller??**

This is my code that I use in app.js and worked:

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

cordova.plugins.email.isAvailable(
  function (isAvailable) {
       alert('Service is available');
  }
);
// Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
// for form inputs)
if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
  cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
}
if(window.StatusBar) {
  // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
  StatusBar.styleDefault();
}
  });
})
```

This is same code in controller.js that not worked (I set my controller in my route):

```
.controller('ApplicationController', function($scope) {
  $scope.sendMail = function () {
    cordova.plugins.email.isAvailable(
      function (isAvailable) {
           alert('Service is not available');
      }
    );
  }
})
```

and this is my click call:

```
  <a ng-click="sendMail()">
  <i class="icon ion-android-forums"></i>
send mail
  </a>
```

This is code works well in $ionicPlatform but don't work in seperate controller file.

Comment: Show the full code of your controller

Comment: Please post code as to how you are calling and defining this function through ng-click

Comment: Thanks for your attention I update my question add more code.

Answer (score -1):

You should use an Angular.js wrapper for this.

Check out [ngCordova](http://ngcordova.com/).

Comment: Ladislav can you please give example? :-)

Answer (score -1):

Try using `window.cordova` instead of `cordova` when referring to the plugin outside of `$ionicPlatform`.